# COM+ component slower on 64 bit server

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic, 64-bit, com+

I have just migrated ASP website and COM+ component from old server to new 64 bit win 2012 server. But One of the functionality where we upload the file onto the server has become very slow. We have used SoftArtison's FileUp assembly.

Same website and component deployed on winxp takes 1 minute to upload the file, and on win 2012 64 bit server about 20 minutes. On winxp FileUp assembly used is older version.

I have just ran out of ideas as on what to do and what could be cause.

Comment: If it's a 32 bit component running on 64 bit windows that might have something to do with the slower performance - don't know if there's anything you can do about it though

Comment: Yes it is 32 bit VB component running on 64 BIT OS. But interestingly it is running faster on other server with same configuration but really slow on the production one. The issue is not related to FileUp assembly it is uploading file in fraction of seconds. Issue I think is with VB component doing post processing of retrieving data from the text file.

Comment: You can contact Softartisans support directly, they're quite helpful - http://fileup.softartisans.com/getting-started-fileup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. But the issue was not related to SoftArtisans FileUp. The issue was regarding the COM+ VB component. Actually I have found the root cause. There was high level string manipulation (split, substring, trim, append, concat) happening while generation of XML and VB does not have StringBuilder, so this was using up lot of memory and consuming time as well. I have moved the XML generation logic to .Net Comvisible dll, deploying the same in GAC and calling dll from VB code. And it is working very quickly now.